# Making Phone call from Android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I set on my Android a new default dialer.
I created an app that make a phone call by click on button that use this code:

```
Intent callIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

But, when I lunch the func of make a call, the call goes out via the old default dialer and not from the new dialer I set as default.

My question is how can I make the call goes out via the new dialer I set as default?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL`?

Answer (score 0):

The way you use is the right one. The difference between `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` and `Intent.ACTION_CALL` is that the first one allows the user to explicitly initiate the call showing the dialer UI. Maybe your custom dailer does not support the intent you send, and because of that there is only one app responding (the default dailer) and Android forwards you there. Otherwise a pop-up would open and let you choose which dailer to use.

Comment: thanks for your answer. when I try to make a call via the default Contacts app, the call go via my new default dialer, so I think the app support this option.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL). There is a note that there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call and that most applications should use the ACTION_DIAL. Have you set the right permission, as well? ACTION_CALL requires: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Comment: I used this permission, and also the CALL_PRIVILEGED permission. the problem is  not to make a call, my problem is to call from my new default dialer and not from the native dialer.

Comment: So then it might be not working through some Android restrictions. From the documentation: **Note: there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call;**. Maybe they want to prevent this through some security reasons.